# Is there a point in specifying than a 1D np.array is Fortran ordered?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Reading some cython code, I ran into

```
cdef double[:] centers = np.zeros(n_samples, order='F')
```

where n_samples is an int, not an iterable. Is there any reason to use `order='F'`, since, the array is 1D?

Comment: This may be set on principle because the array is later passed to a Fortran function. Or there could happen some reshaping of the array later and setting order from the start avoids unnecessary copying. Or it could be a totally redundant result of copy&paste. Hard to tell without further reference how the array is used.

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference to reshape (since it isn't done in place anyway).

Comment: @DavidW although reshape does not work in place the result still refers to the same data if possible. However, I just read that reshape does not guarantee C or F layout anyway. Still, the essential point remains - need more context.

Comment: I agree with the comments above; we can really only speculate. If the code came from [here](https://github.com/EugeneNdiaye/GAPSAFE_SGL/blob/master/sgl_fast.pyx), the arrays are being passed to various [BLAS routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/linalg.cython_blas.html) which expect Fortran-ordered arrays. It's true that this isn't really an issue if the array is 1D anyway, but may have been done just for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short test of the flags of a 1D NumPy array:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.zeros(10).flags
Out[2]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [3]: np.zeros(10, order='F').flags
Out[3]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

So, no, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

No, this shouldnt make any difference. Fortan/C order isnt explicitly tracked; the governing attribute is the strides; if strides is a sequence of length 1, Fortran and C order are the same thing, so the distinction is void.